# Can you have a defined get and a trival set in a property?

Tags: c#, properties

Can you have a defined get and a trivial set in an auto implemented property.

`public double TotalPurchases { get {return a*b*c}; set; }`

Answer: It gives an error:

`...set must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial`

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: `...set must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial`

Comment: exactly the compiler already gave you the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave set with empty braces:

```
public double TotalPurchases { get {return a*b*c; } set{} }
```

or

```
public double TotalPurchases { get {return a*b*c; }  }
```

Comment: Note that this is no longer an auto implemented property and that you cannot set the value of the property anymore this way

Answer (score 6):

No, C# does not allow this. Auto-implemented properties must auto-implement both the getter and setter.

This also very much makes sense. In your example, what should the setter do? Which field should it set?